# eBPF - Is map.update() not causing undefined behaviour?

Tags: ebpf, bpf

I'm completely new to eBPF, I tried to find an answer to this but can't so I was hoping to get some help.

Take Liz's ebpf.py [example](https://github.com/lizrice/ebpf-beginners)

It looks like this:

```
BPF_HASH(clones);

int hello_world(void *ctx) {
   u64 uid;
   u64 counter = 0;
   u64 *p;
   uid = bpf_get_current_uid_gid() & 0xFFFFFFFF;
   p = clones.lookup(&uid);
   if (p != 0) {
      counter = *p;
   }
   counter++;
   clones.update(&uid, &counter);
   return 0;
}
```

This then makes me wonder, for the map named *clones* she calls the update method. She enters a pointer to a stack-allocated variable (*counter*), does this not cause undefined behaviour when the stack frame is deallocated.

A possible option is that the value within the pointer is copied instead of stored as a pointer.

But then, according to this [reference guide](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/reference_guide.md) BPF_HASH can specify the *leaf_type* (value of the map). Meaning you can set it to a struct, which can't necessarily be copied.

I feel like I'm missing something so I'm thankful for any explanation for the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A possible option is that the value within the pointer is copied instead of stored as a pointer.

That's correct. The value pointed to by the pointer is copied in the memory buffer allocated for the map's value.

> Meaning you can set it to a struct, which can't necessarily be copied.

Why wouldn't that be possible? Note the kernel doesn't really care that it's a struct. It sees a pointer to a memory buffer with a size (the map's value size); it simply copies whatever is in that buffer to the memory buffer allocated for the map value.

Comment: Okay, it can copy a struct but you can't deep copy, for example: a struct for an element in a double linked list. That would mean that adjacent elements now pointed to a different memory address than the one in the MAP. It would also mean that if you changed the value of the list then the pointers within the element in the MAP might point to deallocated values. 
This gets very dangerous any time a struct containing a ptr is copied. But maybe that's allowed (though I thought I heard somewhere that it was designed to not be able to crash the kernel)

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't perform a deep copy and thus the values pointed to by pointer fields in the struct won't be copied. If you then try to retrieve such a struct from the map and try to dereference its pointer field, the verifier will reject your program.

Comment: Ah, okay! That's awesome that they can infer that. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: In this case it's more that they don't infer anything specific for what's loaded from the map value memory. The map value pointer is seen as `PTR_TO_MAP_VALUE`. Anything loaded from that pointer will be tracked as a non-pointer type and the verifier will reject any memory load from it. You can see that at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.10/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L4756. Glad I could help!